# Matplotlib Subplot axes sharing: Apply to every other plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to find a way to apply the shared axes parameters of subplot() to every other plot in a series of subplots.

I've got the following code, which uses data from `RPM4`, based on rows in `fpD`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2*(fpD['name'].count()), sharex=True, figsize=(6,fpD['name'].count()*2),
                      gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[5,1]*fpD['name'].count()})

for i, r in fpD.iterrows():
    RPM4[RPM4['name'] == RPM3.iloc[i,0]].plot(x='date', y='RPM', ax=ax[(2*i)], legend=False)
    RPM4[RPM4['name'] == RPM3.iloc[i,0]].plot(kind='area', color='lightgrey', x='date', y='total', ax=ax[(2*i)+1], 
                                                  legend=False,)
    ax[2*i].set_title('test', fontsize=12)

    plt.tight_layout()
```

Which produces an output that is very close to what I need. It loops through the 'name' column in a table and produces two plots for each, and displays them as subplots:

[image]

As you can see, the `sharex` parameter works fine for me here, since I want all the plots to share the same axis.

However, what I'd really like is for all the even-numbered (bigger) plots to share the same y axis, and for the odd-numbered (small grey) plots to all share a different y axis.

Any help on accomplishing this is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51776155/4124317).

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Still having trouble getting the ```sharex``` to work. Have tried ```axes.append(fig.add_subplot(gse[i], sharex=True))``` but thats giving me a ```TypeError: cannot create weak reference to 'bool' object```. Any idea why?

Comment: The sharex argument must be given the axes with which you want to share.